# Elasticsearch filter by whitelist

Tags: elasticsearch, whitelist

I have a list of string values which used as a whitelist.
For example:

```
{
    "whitelist": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

In Elastic Search I have many documents, each one contains an array of strings, like:

doc_1

```
{
    "values": ["a", "y", "b"]
}
```

doc_2

```
{
    "values": ["a", "c"]
}
```

I want to filter out all the documents that contain at least one value that is not contained in the whitelist.

In the example above, the requested result is **doc_2**, as it doesn't contain any value which is not in the whitelist, while **doc_1** does contain value "y".

Is there any way to do such a thing without an external code outside of ElasticSearch?

Comment: You wish to return those documents whose values array, do not contain the elements from whitelist array is that right?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct

Comment: Actually Not! On the contrary. I want to return all the documents whose values array do not contain any value that is NOT one of the values in the whitelist.

Comment: can you update your question, with the output document as well? Just to help us clearly understand, the question wordings are a bit tricky.

Comment: Sure. Question updated